# TextWatcher not executing several setText llines

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Using TextWatcher to change letters, it seems to only execute the last line (For example it would change `c` to `3` but ignore the changes prior. If I delete the last line (c to 3) it would only then start changing `b` to `2`. Im not sure why this is or how to fix it. (Java is new to me)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextWatcher tt = null;

private TextView textView;
private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    tt = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            et.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
            tv.setText(et.getText().toString().replace("a", "1"));
            tv.setText(et.getText().toString().replace("b", "2"));
            tv.setText(et.getText().toString().replace("c", "3"));
            et.addTextChangedListener(tt);


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                et.setSelection(s.length());

        }
    };
    et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Comment: Review: Adding some sample out might help a bit more. For the rest your Q looks ok!

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided there are 3 times `setText` executed for `TextView`. So, it keeps the result only of the last call. If you want to display result of all replacements, do it in single String:

```java
et.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
tv.setText(et.getText().toString().replace("a", "1").replace("b", "2").replace("c", "3"));
et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

**EDIT**:

Of course, you can execute transformation step-by-step:

```
et.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
String s = et.getText().toString();
s = s.replace("a", "1");
s = s.replace("b", "2");
s = s.replace("c", "3");
tv.setText(s);
et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Method `String.replace` doesn't change String, but returns new one, so we need to reassign results of each replacement (I just assign to `s` again and again to prevent unused references)

Comment: Ill give that a shot. Thank you for the quick and easy explanation. 
I am curious though if its possible to do that but make it look more clean instead of one super long line?

Comment: @Buddhism, review updates in the asnwer, I hope it helps